# Can't set the frame rate when recording a video with VecVideoRecorder

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I have a working RL model and set up that produce a video for me - however becuase the model is reasonably good, the videos are very short (reach a desitination therfore better = shorter)

Is there a way to drop the frame rate of the video output? I know it can be done with a gif. And that it can be done with ffmpeg but I can't workout how to pass it down.

I've dropped the fps in my environment from 50>10 expecting the video to be 5 times as long but that didn't work.

Save me stackoverflow you're my only hope. (appart from posting on github)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say that you dropped the fps from 50 to 10, I assume you changed `env.metadata.video.frames_per_second`, which initializes to `50` (for `gym` versions less than `0.22.0`):

```
{
  'render.modes': ['human', 'rgb_array'],
  'video.frames_per_second': 50
}
```

Starting with `gym` 0.22.0, [VideoRecorder](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/0.26.2/gym/wrappers/monitoring/video_recorder.py#L91) class gets the `frames_per_sec` to write the video with:

```
env.metadata.get("render_fps", 30)
```

Setting `env.metadata["render_fps"] = 4` should result in a slowed down video.

Comment: Thanks I had set render_fps in the environment already. I tried both:



env.metadata['video.frames_per_second']=4


env.metadata["render_fps"] = 4


And neither of them made a difference. Could this be an anaconda implementation thing - its still gym=0.21 I think

Comment: Looks like the current, or last week anyway 2023/02/01, anaconda SB uses gym=0.21. so it was 'video.frames_per_second':4

It only worked if I put it in the environment though - setting it like env.metadata["video.frames_per_second"] = 4 didn't work.

Comment: I've marked it as the answer but I guess updating it to say which versions they apply to would be helpful for future reference.

Thanks!

Comment: I just added the versions, the syntax `env.metadata["video.frames_per_second"] = 4` is the only one I could get to work. I guess you defined a custom environment and declared the metadata as a JSON.